# VALARM from google calendar (ics) not working

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have the following .ics file. I imported it in google calendar. Email notification and push notification worked fine until the bening of March; now I don't receive any notification at all. Am I doing something wrong or something changed on Google Calendar?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:CalendarName
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Rome
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Turno:Name
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20201124
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20201125
DTSTAMP:20220301T083119Z
UID:abcd1e2f3g4hijqlmnopqrs56u@google.com
SEQUENCE:0
CREATED:20201117T101143Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20201117T101144Z
LOCATION:
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Name1
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-P30M
END:VALARM
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:EMAIL
ATTENDEE:myemail@gmail.com
DESCRIPTION:Name2
SUMMARY:NAME
TRIGGER;RELATED=END:-P1D
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: I've checked Google Calendar resources but it seems there's no new/ongoing issue about VALARM suddenly stops working. It seems there's nothing wrong with your setup. If this issue is consistent even when re-importing your .ICS file, then perhaps you may report this behavior at [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) & include detailed information of the issue to be further looked on.